# Flash stream player (tutorial?)

Tags: actionscript, audio, stream, flash

I'm working at a radio station in my free time. I host a radio show there and currently were building a new website for the show. There is a audio stream available but there's no flahs player or what so ever, so i decided to build one for the new website. I know a bit about flash, i can create animations etc but i have no knowledge about actionscript... Could someone tell me where i could find a tutorial about this stuff?

This is the content of the asx file from the stream (http://content.streamone.nl/livestream/ne48FnM3kp.asx) :

```
<ASX version = "3.0">

  <Abstract>Served by StreamOne - Streaming Media Platform</Abstract>
  <Title>Seaport FM</Title>
  <Author>NA</Author>
  <Copyright>Copyright</Copyright>
  <Param NAME="Prebuffer" Value="True" />

  <Entry>
    <Ref href="http://icecast.streamone.nl/ne48FnM3kp" />
    <Title>Seaport FM</Title>
    <Author>NA</Author>
    <Copyright>Copyright</Copyright>
    <Abstract></Abstract>
  </Entry>

</ASX>
```

I have searched on google etc but i cant find anything i can understand

Greetz, rutgerinc

Answer (score 0):

[two](http://wonderfl.net/c/3dVV) simple [examples](http://wonderfl.net/c/5yZq). 
and reference: [flash.media.Video](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html), [flash.net.NetConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html) and [flash.net.NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html)

Comment: Hey, thx for the response but the examples are video.. Can i use it with the url i provided above? The references are all japanese to me, i have no programming skills or what so ever. But thank anyway

Comment: @ Rutgerinc - it's an audio stream?

Comment: @ Rutgerinc - it seems very hard and possible only in theory : the only way to play it with as3 is to parse asx format manually